# Can this be done in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a Parent table called Run, that has Shifts as a child foreign key and those shifts have descriptions in their table. I need to select the Description of a child shift in a query and access the Description of that shift to compare to another shift.

here are the table descriptions:
Run

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| RunId                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| RunType              | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Plant                | varchar(2)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| Warehouse            | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| LegacyId             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| RunDate              | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| Shift                | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| NumEmployees         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| DryersRan            | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| HogfuelDelivered     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ScheduledStart       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ScheduledEnd         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ScheduledHours       | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Downtime             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ProductLength        | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ProductWidth         | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ProductThickness     | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Species              | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| NumBlocks            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| TestRun              | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| AveDiameter          | decimal(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| BlockScale           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| LogScale             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| NumSpinouts          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Pieces               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Footage              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Surface              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Coreline             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Dryer1               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Dryer2               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Dryer3               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Sander               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Redry                | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| GradeStamped         | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Status               | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Notes                | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| InventoryTransaction | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| LastEdited           | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| LastEditedBy         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| LegacyRun            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| WorkCenter           | varchar(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

RunItem:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| ItemId       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| ItemType     | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| Run          | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| LegacyRun    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| WorkCenter   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Product      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| DayProduced  | date        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Source       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| SourceShift  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| PieceCount   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Surface      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Coreline     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Footage      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| LastEdited   | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| LastEditedBy | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Bundle       | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

This is the Query that I've tried so far and it wont let me do (i.Shift iss) how can this be done?

```
update RunItem i, Run r, i.Shift iss, r.Shift rs 
set i.ItemId = (SELECT RunId from Run r where r.LegacyRun = i.LegacyRun and 
rs.Description
 = is.Description
and r.WorkCenter != i.WorkCenter;
```

gives this error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'i.Shift' doesn't exist
```

UPDATE:

```
select r.RunId, i.Run, r.WorkCenter as runWork, i.WorkCenter as itemWork,
 r.Footage, i.LegacyRun as itemLegacy from Run r, RunItem i where r.RunId = i.Run
 and r.WorkCenter != i.WorkCenter and RunDate >= '2016-02-01' and RunDate <= '2016-02-29';

| 39550 | 39550 | P3-LAYUP      | P3-SPREADER |  260818 |      21280 |
| 39553 | 39553 | P3-LAYUP      | P3-SPREADER |  267421 |      21281 |
| 39566 | 39566 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  351547 |      21286 |
| 39569 | 39569 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  527049 |      21287 |
| 39605 | 39605 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  460826 |      21316 |
| 39605 | 39605 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  460826 |      21316 |
| 39605 | 39605 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  460826 |      21316 |
| 39608 | 39608 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  458272 |      21317 |
| 39625 | 39625 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SPREADER |  503324 |      21327 |
| 39628 | 39628 | P3-LAYUP      | P3-SPREADER |  339615 |      21328 |
| 39628 | 39628 | P3-LAYUP      | P3-SPREADER |  339615 |      21328 |
+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+

select RunId, WorkCenter, Shift,
 LegacyRun from Run where Footage is null
 and RunDate >='2016-02-01' and RunDate <='2016-02-29';


| 39552 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-DAY-SPREAD   |     21280 |
| 39555 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-SWING-SPREAD |     21281 |
| 39568 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-DAY-SPREAD   |     21286 |
| 39571 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-SWING-SPREAD |     21287 |
| 39607 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-DAY-SPREAD   |     21316 |
| 39609 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-SWING-SPREAD |     21317 |
| 39626 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-DAY-SPREAD   |     21327 |
| 39629 | P3-SPREADER   | P3-SWING-SPREAD |     21328 |
| 39647 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-DAY-SL       |     21339 |
| 39649 | P3-8FTSAWLINE | P3-SWING-SL     |     21340 |
+-------+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

In the table above I'm selecting the runs where the RunItem WorkCenter and Run WorkCenter don't match, this tells me that under that Run
Some of the RunItems are pointing to the wrong run. The table below is the Table where Runs have a footage value of zero which means they don't have runItems pointing to them.
So what I need is when the RunItem WorkCenter and Run WorkCenter don't match grab the LegacyRun(RunId) and that Legacy RunShift, point all the RunItems where the workCenters don't match to the Run
that has the same LegacyRun(Id) and same Shift.Description and the LegacyRun.

UPDATE_2:
lets take the first from the top table

```
| 39550 | 39550 | P3-LAYUP      | P3-SPREADER |  260818 |      21280 |
```

notice that the legacyRun(Id) is 21280
it just so happends that the top rows of the bottom Table also has the LegacyRun of 21280

if we select ItemId, WorkCenter from RunItem where Run = 39550(run from the top table where the runItem workcenter doesnt math the run);
we get:

```
+--------+-------------+
| ItemId | WorkCenter  |
+--------+-------------+
| 110336 | P3-LAYUP    |
| 110344 | P3-SPREADER |
+--------+-------------+
```

we know we have to point that runItem with the WorkCenter of spreader to First row of the bottom table that doesn't have runItems pointing to it.

so to fix this one row we do:

```
update RunItem set Run = 39552 where ItemId = 110344;
```

I could go through and manually do this but I want something that can update all rows

Comment: The `UPDATE` clause just lists the tables, columns go in the `SET` clause.

Comment: You use foreign keys in the `ON` clause of a `JOIN`, you don't list them in the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: What do you mean? @Barmar

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired result? I can't figure out how the `Shift` table is related to these tables? It looks like you need to join with that table twice, once for `iss` and once for `rs`, but I don't understand what the joining condition would be.

Comment: @Sam_in_real_life Something like `UPDATE RunItem i JOIN Run r ON r.LegacyRun = i.LegacyRun JOIN Shift is ON is.Shift = r.Shift`

Comment: I'm Sorry @Barmar , but what is that join doing? I don't know how to build my query out, with this method.

Comment: It's relating the tables through their foreign keys, just like `JOIN` does in `SELECT`.

Comment: If you show the data and desired result, I'll be able to post an answer and explain the whole thing. Until then, all I can do is give you hints about the general syntax.

Comment: Ok, I'm updating the question. @Barmar

Comment: Not there yet. Can you give an example of some of the updates that should be done from that data?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to understand this, but I think I have to give up. I don't see Description or RunShift anywhere in the tables.

Comment: @Barmar I got the query I needed thanks to your JOIN tip. the query was a lot simpler than I originally thought it was going to be. `UPDATE RunItem i JOIN Run r ON r.LegacyRun = i.LegacyRun AND r.WorkCenter = i.WorkCenter JOIN Run rr ON rr.RunId = i.Run SET  i.Run = r.RunId where i.WorkCenter != rr.WorkCenter;`

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Query I needed thanks to @Barmar:

```
UPDATE RunItem i JOIN Run r 
ON r.LegacyRun = i.LegacyRun 
AND r.WorkCenter = i.WorkCenter 
JOIN Run rr 
ON rr.RunId = i.Run 
SET  i.Run = r.RunId 
where i.WorkCenter != rr.WorkCenter;
```

This is a much simpler and elegant Query once I added the `JOIN` `ON`.